# Change innertext of element dynamically inside for loop of a function

Tags: javascript, for-loop, innertext

Issue : Upon entering a higher number like 10000, innertext of the new paragraph element is updated only after the for loop ends. Please help to make the innertext get updated for each number.

The increment function is called when an onchange event happens after sending a number as a input to the input element.

JAVASCRIPT :

```
function increment() {
    var count = document.getElementById('ac_count').value; //ac_count is the id of the input element
    var stat = document.createElement("p");
    stat.id = "current_status";
    stat.innerText = "";
    document.body.appendChild(stat);
    stat.style.display = "block";
    for (g = 1; g < count; g++) {
        stat.innerText = Number(g + 1) + " out of " + count + " records have been processed";
    }
}
```

Comment: my guess is that loop runs so fast you don't even notice the other numbers. If you want to make it visible, try using `setTimeout` possibly with a `recursive` function to slow it down.

Comment: I gave a larger number like 10000, it takes some 5 seconds before the following text appears : "10000 out of 10000 records have been processed". On using console.log inside the for loop i can see "2 out of 10000 records have been processed" upto "9999 out of 10000 records have been processed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DOM doesn't redraw until the executing thread is free. You need to introduce async delays to your code to see a progressive update.

```js
function increment() {
  var count = document.getElementById('ac_count').value;
  var stat = document.createElement("p");
  stat.id = "current_status";
  document.body.appendChild(stat);

  var g = 1
  var itvl = setInterval(function() {
    update(g);
    g += Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1
    if (g >= count) {
      clearInterval(itvl);
      update(count);
    }
  }, 10)

  function update(g) {
    stat.textContent = g + " out of " + count + " records have been processed";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type=number value=10000 id=ac_count>
<button onclick="increment()">CLICK ME</button>
```

Comment: Fantastic buddy! This is what I wanted. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not suggesting that this is a good solution, but this should achieve the effect you're looking for

```
function increment() {
    var count = document.getElementById('ac_count').value; //ac_count is the id of the input element
    var stat = document.createElement("p");
    stat.id = "current_status";
    stat.innerText = "";
    document.body.appendChild(stat);
    stat.style.display = "block";
    updateInnerText(0, count);
}

function updateInnerText(number, max){
    if(number < max){
        stat.innerText = Number(number + 1) + " out of " + count + " records have been processed";
        setTimeout(function(){
            updateInnerText(number+1, max);
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" value="100" id="stats">
<button onclick="changeNumber()"></button>
 function changeNumber() {
        let count = document.querySelector('#stats').value;
        let stats = document.createElement('p');
        document.body.appendChild(stats);
        var g = 1;
        var interval = setInterval(function () {
            if (g <= count) {
                update(g);
            } else {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
            g++;
        }, 10);
        function update(g) {
            stats.textContent = g;
        }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).